# SQL Join multi tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I got these 3 tables:

```
fieldValues|values|formCustomizeValues |
-----------|------|--------------------|
FieldID    |ID    |FormCustomizeFieldID|
ValueID    |Name  |FieldID             |
           |      |ValueID             | 
-----------|------|--------------------|
```

And the data on these tables looks like this:

```
fieldValues|values|formCustomizeValues|
-----------|------|-------------------|
4          |1     |1                  |
1          |James |4                  |
-----------|------|3                  |
4          |2     |-------------------|
2          |Ben   |
-----------|------|
           |3     |
           |Daniel|
```

What i'm trying to do is to get all the values for the specific field.
so lets say i want to grab all the values with the `FieldID` that equals to `4`, i should get:

```
James
Ben
Daniel
```

But i tried 5 different queries and the only things i'm getting is or `James, Ben` or `Daniel`.

This is the query that returning me zero `results`:

```
SELECT v.* FROM `fieldValues` fv
LEFT JOIN `values` v ON fv.ValueID = v.ID
LEFT JOIN formCustomizeValues fcv ON fcv.FieldID = fv.FieldID AND fcv.ValueID = v.ID
WHERE fv.FieldID = 4 AND fcv.FormCustomizeFieldID = 1
```

And that query returning me only `James, Ben`:

```
SELECT v.* FROM `fieldValues` fv
LEFT JOIN `values` v ON fv.ValueID = v.ID
LEFT JOIN formCustomizeValues fcv ON fcv.ValueID = v.ID
WHERE fv.FieldID = 4
```

How can i get them all together?
Any help will be appreciated!!
Thanks!

Here is SQLfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43b56/1

Comment: Your query looks for values for field 4.  `James` and `Ben` look like the right answers to me.

Comment: @Brandon But what makes fieldValues and formCustomizeValues relational is the FieldID, but i only want to take the ValueID from fieldValues that his FieldID is 4, and the ValueID from formCustomizeValues that his FieldID is also 4 and filter it by FormCustomizeFieldID, because maybe i will have another formCustomizeValues with the same FieldID but different FormCustomizeFieldID

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean? i added sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43b56/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want :

- 1 Query to retrieve names via fieldValues
- 1 Query to retrieve names via formCustomizeValues
- Union to join both result

The query :

```
SELECT
    v.`Name`
FROM
    `values` v
    INNER JOIN  `fieldValues` as fv
        on v.`ID` = fv.`ValueID`
        and fv.`FieldID` = 4
UNION
SELECT
    v.`Name`
FROM
    `values` v
    INNER JOIN  `formCustomizeValues` as fcv
        on v.`ID` = fcv.`ValueID`
        and fcv.`FieldID` = 4
```

Here the [SQLFIDDLE UPDATED](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43b56/20)

Comment: This request totally scalable, may you precise what is your idea ?

Comment: i'm building dynamic fields with rules for each user

Comment: Okay, at the moment the query is scalable and optimized. The weakness in this query is that you are using UNION so you are doing a distinct between names to not retrieve twice the name. If you want to not duplicate your user roles in both query, use `SELECT ID, Name FROM (both_queries_in_answer) WHERE here_your_rules`. This is not performance killer.

Comment: The rules are applied differently, i have table of rules for each form, then i'm building a string if statement and eval it, and then i apply all the fields building process inside the if

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside any criticisms of the schema design…

```
SELECT v.name 
  FROM `values` v
  LEFT JOIN `fieldValues` fv ON fv.ValueID = v.ID
  LEFT JOIN `formCustomizeValues` fcv ON fcv.ValueID = v.ID
 WHERE fv.FieldID = 4
    OR fcv.FormCustomizeFieldID = 1
;
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43b56/30).

***Update***

I see now that your first query that you said resulted in no rows was actually pretty close. You want all the rows from `values` that are defined in either `fieldValues` ***or*** `formCustomizeValues`. Using `AND` results in no rows because no row meets both conditions. Therefore you want to use `OR` or use a `UNION` as Ryx5 has suggested.

```
SELECT v.name 
  FROM `values` v
  LEFT JOIN `fieldValues` fv ON fv.ValueID = v.ID
  LEFT JOIN `formCustomizeValues` fcv ON fcv.ValueID = v.ID
 WHERE fv.FieldID = 4
    OR fcv.FormCustomizeFieldID = 1
;
```

[Updated updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43b56/33).

Comment: Please tell me your thoughts about the schema. I'm always seeking for new things!

Comment: @Bonik this query is really fine too, and perhaps more like you need for what you want (about users rules)

Comment: @Ryx5 sorry but its not suitable to me. i need to filter it by FormCustomizedFieldID so the WHERE statement with the OR is not helping

Comment: I'm not a fan of [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html) models in the first place. Even so, there is [a more-or-less standard way to do EAV](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway) and this seems like a non-standard implementation.

Comment: As far as filtering by a different column from `formCustomizeValues`, you can substitute whatever column is necessary into the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @ob1quixote Would you discuses with me more about it? if yes, get in touch with me yoni@xlrx.co